# Hide Specific Subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot 1 figure with a handful of different subplots. The subplot set up is (2,6), but I would like to hide the last two subplots ([delete the plots outlined in black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPaUd.png)).

This is how I have set my code up:

```
fig, ((L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7), (R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7)) = plt.subplots(2,7)
fig.set_size_inches(15, 8)


L1.plot(x, y)
R1.plot(x, y)
L2.plot(x, y)
R2.plot(x, y)
L3.plot(x, y)
R3.plot(x, y)
L4.plot(x, y)
R4.plot(x, y)
L5.plot(x, y)
R5.plot(x, y)
L6.plot(x, y)
R6.plot(x, y)
L7.plot(x, y)
R7.plot(x, y)
```

I have attempted [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/euax0e/how_to_make_a_matplotlib_subplot_invisible/), but because I am creating multiple axis, I am unsure how to apply this to my code. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Indeed it does, thank you! I should have searched harder.